# Android Navigation component: No NavHostFragments found error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am currently implementing the Navigation Component into my app but it seems finding the NavHostFragment just doesn't work no matter what I do.

I have tried, rebuilding, invalidating, and restarting, changing the names around, and updating my Android Studio but nothing seems to work. I think this is also the reason why I get an error when trying to get the NavController in my `MainActivity.kt` file as it returns null.

Android Studio version 4.0.1

**nav_graph.xml image**:

[image]

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.movieapp.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_searchMovieFragment"
            app:destination="@id/searchMovieFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchMovieFragment"
        android:name="com.example.movieapp.ui.search.SearchMovieFragment"
        android:label="SearchMovieFragment" />
</navigation>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/appbar" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_bar, menu)
        return true
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {}

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        dataBinding {
            enabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // Retrofit Libraries
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'

    // Picasso Library
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Navigation libraries
    def nav_version = "2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private val navController by lazy {
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment) as NavHostFragment).navController
    }
```

Your `navController` is null because I think `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment)` returns null. The id of your navHost is `R.id.nav_host_fragment` according to your activity layout.

Answer (score 16):

The way I was able to resolve the issue was by going to the Activity.xml and changing the fragment class/component tag from `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` to just `fragment`. It then showed up in the hosts panel of the navigation graph.

Comment: Any idea why the linter suggests "Replace the <fragment> tag with  androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView"?  Apparently I followed it's advice and broke everything ;)

Comment: @Jay It's an update but a broken one.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I solved this by creating the NavHostFragment from the **Design**, **Palette** and then assign the respective navigation resource file.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhost), You can also use the Layout Editor to add a NavHostFragment.

1. In your list of project files, double-click on your activity's layout XML file to open it in the Layout Editor.
2. Within the Palette pane, choose the Containers category, or alternatively search for "NavHostFragment".
3. Drag the NavHostFragment view onto your activity.
4. Next, in the Navigation Graphs dialog that appears, choose the corresponding navigation graph to associate with this NavHostFragment, and then click OK.

> YOU MAY NEED TO RESTART THE ANDROID STUDIO AFTER THIS (not mentioned
> in the doc)

Also, you may see "fragment" instead of "FragmentContainerView" when you try to add fragment using above method.

Comment: It was the restart that did the job for me...

Answer (score 3):

You can find `NavController` in activity as:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu_bar, menu)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Was about to reply the same, this is it. Also notice how it's R.id.nav_host_fragment instead of the fragment in the nav_graph.xml (main_fragment)

Comment: @asad mahmood when I replace it to ```<fragment>``` it tells me I should replace it back to ```FragmentContainerView```. When should I use each?

Comment: @efoc if `FragmentContainerView` works then don't change it. Actually `NavHostFragment` uses `FragmentContainerView` in nav Version 2.2.0 for  [Improved Animation Support](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.2.0)

Comment: You can still use the `<fragment>` tag, but `FragmentContainerView` is the new recommended standard. In short, from now on, everywhere you can use `<fragment>`, you should use `FragmentContainerView` instead. Maybe this article will tell you more why: https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentcontainerview-292f393f9ccf . Your code should work with `FragmentContainerView`, and if it does, I don't see any reason not to use it instead of `<fragment>`, as it is the recommended component.

Answer (score 3):

For me I added `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` inside `FragmentContainerView` and worked with me

Answer (score 2):

we should make sure to write this line

**android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"**

```
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navController"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Initally we dont have NavHostFragments. You pointed each fragment to each other, created movement actions but you need something to host this movement. That is where `navigation host fragment` comes into play. it is NavHostFragment that sort of swaps in our fragments as necessary inside a given layout. So what layout should hold this nav fragment. it is the layout that gets inflated during the main activity. So open `activity_main.xml`.

You should add `Containers/NavHostFragment`

[image]

When you choose NavHostFragment to drag, you will see the available host fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue even though I had added all of the required `name` and `fragment` suggestions from above; however, when I did an `invalidate cache and restart` it solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can solve that problem.

> // TODO: Screen enum, enum class LunchTrayScreen(@StringRes val title: Int){,Start(title = R.string.app_name),,Entree(title = R.string.choose_entree),,SideDish(title = R.string.choose_side_dish),Accompaniment(title =R.string.choose_accompaniment),
> Checkout(title = R.string.order_checkout)}

> // TODO: AppBar

@Composable
fun LunchTrayApp() {// TODO: Create Controller and initialization
val navController = rememberNavController(),val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState(),val currentScreen = LunchTrayScreen.valueOf(backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?:LunchTrayScreen.Start.name)// Create ViewModel,val viewModel: OrderViewModel = viewModel()

> Scaffold(topBar = {LunchTrayAppBar(currentScreenTitle = currentScreen.title,canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() })) { innerPadding ->
> val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

> // TODO: Navigation host
> NavHost(navController = navController,startDestination = LunchTrayScreen.Start.name,modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
> ){composable(route = LunchTrayScreen.Start.name){StartOrderScreen(onStartOrderButtonClicked = {navController.navigate(LunchTrayScreen.Entree.name)})}
> composable(route = LunchTrayScreen.Entree.name){ EntreeMenuScreen(
> options = com.example.lunchtray.datasource.DataSource.entreeMenuItems,
> onCancelButtonClicked = { viewModel.resetOrder(), navController.popBackStack(LunchTrayScreen.Start.name, inclusive = false)},onNextButtonClicked = {navController.navigate(LunchTrayScreen.SideDish.name) },onSelectionChanged =  { item -> viewModel.updateEntree(item)})}
> composable(route = LunchTrayScreen.SideDish.name){SideDishMenuScreen(
> options =com.example.lunchtray.datasource.DataSource.sideDishMenuItems,
> onCancelButtonClicked = { viewModel.resetOrder() navController.popBackStack(LunchTrayScreen.Start.name, inclusive = false)},onNextButtonClicked = { navController.navigate(LunchTrayScreen.Accompaniment.name) },onSelectionChanged = { item -> viewModel.updateSideDish(item)}
> )}composable(route = LunchTrayScreen.Accompaniment.name){AccompanimentMenuScreen(options = com.example.lunchtray.datasource.DataSource.accompanimentMenuItems,onCancelButtonClicked = { viewModel.resetOrder() navController.popBackStack(LunchTrayScreen.Start.name, inclusive = false)},onNextButtonClicked = {navController.navigate(LunchTrayScreen.Checkout.name) },onSelectionChanged = { item -> viewModel.updateAccompaniment(item)}
> )}composable(route = LunchTrayScreen.Checkout.name){CheckoutScreen(orderUiState = uiState,onNextButtonClicked = { viewModel.resetOrder()navController.popBackStack(LunchTrayScreen.Start.name, inclusive = false)},onCancelButtonClicked = { viewModel.resetOrder()navController.popBackStack(LunchTrayScreen.Start.name, inclusive = false)}) }}}}

> @Composablefun LunchTrayAppBar(@StringRes currentScreenTitle: Int,
> canNavigateBack : Boolean,navigateUp: () -> Unit,modifier : Modifier = Modifier){TopAppBar (title = { Text(stringResource(currentScreenTitle))},modifier = modifier,navigationIcon = {if(canNavigateBack){IconButton(onClick = navigateUp){Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack,contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.back_button) )}}})}

> Another example would be:
> za currentScreen you will write CupcakeScreen//from enum class
> @Composablefun CupcakeApp(viewModel: OrderViewModel = viewModel(),navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
> ) {val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
> val currentScreen = CupcakeScreen.valueOf(backStackEntry?.destination?.route ?: CupcakeScreen.Start.name)Scaffold(topBar = {CupcakeAppBar(currentScreen = currentScreen,canNavigateBack = navController.previousBackStackEntry != null,navigateUp = { navController.navigateUp() } )}
> ) { innerPadding ->val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()NavHost(navController = navController,startDestination = CupcakeScreen.Start.name,
> modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)){composable(route = CupcakeScreen.Start.name){StartOrderScreen(quantityOptions = quantityOptions,onNextButtonClicked = { viewModel.setQuantity(it)
> navController.navigate(CupcakeScreen.Flavor.name)})}